# How to remove grandparents or grandchildren from JPA response?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm creating a simple REST server powered by Spring Boot framework.

One of the entity that I've created has a self-join relationship and I added OneToMany and ManyToOne tags to handle that relationship in the model class.

The problem that I'm having is, during the development, I've noticed the returned object could have its grandparents or grandchildren object detail.

This is mysql script for the entity

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
  Item_Id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Item_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Item_Description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  Item_RegisterDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Item_RemainingQuantity INT,
  Item_ResignDate DATETIME,
  Item_ParentId BIGINT,
  Item_isEndProduct Boolean NOT NULL,
  Item_UnitPrice INT,

  UNIQUE (Item_Name),    
  CONSTRAINT FK_Item_Category FOREIGN KEY (Item_ParentId) REFERENCES Item(Item_Id)
);
```

This is the java code for the self-join relationship

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference(value = "item-childrenitems")
@JoinColumn(name="item_parentid")
public Item getItemParent() {
  return this.itemParent;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="itemParent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference(value = "item-childrenitems")
public List<Item> getChildrenItems(){
  return this.childrenItems;
}
```

My data is

Entry has Salad and it has Chicken Salad

when I query for Entry, the response contains Salad as the child object of Entry but Salad has Chicken Salad as its child.. So one query for an object returns every grand or possibly grand-grandchildren.

Currently, I'm trying to address this issue by creating Service layer and detaching every grandchildren from an object in the Service layer. However, this solutions is not prevent the server from sending multiple queries to DB to retrieve grandchildren data (a bit of performance concern).

What is the best practice to not retrieve grandparents or grandchildren data?

Another question is...
Is there way to retrieve both of parent and children data for an object? i.e bidirectional. I know I need to remove @JsonBackReference tag in order to retrieve parent item but if I remove it, there is an infinite loop problem..

Comment: how do you query Entry ? Your relationships are loaded Lazily here (FetchType.LAZY), so the child entry is retreived only when you call the getter. If your query calls this getter , it is normal to get the child.

Comment: I'm querying findAll() by extending  PagingAndSortingRepository interface and it's desired to see child item but I don't want to retrieve child's child.